# Extract words with specific tags from a list of arrays

Tags: python, list, pos-tagger

I want to get words with only "NNP" tags from the list which looks like this:

> [[('Original', 'JJ'), [('Respectfully', 'RB'), (',', ',')],
>    [('Detective', 'NNP'),
>     ('.', '.'),
>     ('H.', 'NNP'),
>     ('!', '.'),
>     ('Thompson', 'NNP'),
>     ('#', '#'),
>     ('1032', 'CD')]]

I've tried:

```py
nouns = [word for (word, pos) in pos_sentences if pos == 'NNP']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-187-0de3a4db4bba>", line 1, in <module>
    nouns = [word for (word, pos) in pos_sentences if pos == 'NNP']

  File "<ipython-input-187-0de3a4db4bba>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    nouns = [word for (word, pos) in pos_sentences if pos == 'NNP']

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I want only the words with tags "NNP" but do not know the way to iterate through the list like this one

Comment: You probably want to flatten your double list into a single list first, then your above code should work. You have a `list of list of tuples` but your code is written for `list of tuples`

Comment: Your provided example for pos_sentences does not have a standard formatting:

[[('Original', 'JJ'), [('Respectfully', 'RB'), (',', ',')], [('Detective', 'NNP'), ('.', '.'), ('H.', 'NNP'), ('!', '.'), ('Thompson', 'NNP'), ('#', '#'), ('1032', 'CD')]]

so your attempt to filter the list's items will be really hard if not down right impossible. Are you fix your sample input?

Comment: @jcmack You got it right. I am unable to get proper tags from the text. I have the input from a .docx file. I tried different encodings but did not get it converted to a proper format. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the list first:

```py
import functools
pos_sentences = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, pos_sentences) # Flattens the list
nouns = [word for (word, pos) in pos_sentences if pos == 'NNP'] # Do as you did before
```